# C++ Deallocating memory giving me aborted dump?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, segmentation-fault, abort

I have a deconstructor that is suppose to deallocate the pointers I made but it's not working as it should. Heres part of my class that declares all the pointers

```
private:
    struct Edge {
        Vertex* node;
    };

    struct Vertex {
        vector< Edge > adjList;
        Vertex *path;

    };

    vector<Vertex*> vertices;
    priority_queue< Vertex* > pq;
```

And occasionally I declare new vertexs in functions like so `Vertex* v = new Vertex`. I've been told that I do not have to worry about deleting these pointers. Heres my function that deallocates my memory that is called by my deconstructor

```
void makeEmpty( ) {
    for(int i = 0; i < total; ++i)
        makeEmpty( vertices[ i ] );
    total = 0;
}

void makeEmpty( Vertex * & v ) {
    for( int i = 0; i < v->adjList.size(); ++i ){
        //delete v->adjList[ i ].node;
        //v->adjList[ i ].node = nullptr;
    }
    if ( v->path != nullptr ) {
        makeEmpty( v->path);
        delete v;
        v = nullptr;
    }
}
```

I commented out my `adjList` because I was experimenting with different ways on how to make this worked but nothing is. Can anyone help me?

Forgot to mention that all of these pointers are related to the same vertex/node. All of the vertex/nodes that are used is inside my vertices

Edit: I got it to worked, turns out I was overcomplicating things and just needed to do this

```
void makeEmpty( Vertex * & v ) {
        delete v;
        v = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: I think if you have cycles in your structure (a vertex leading to a vertex leading to ... leading to the first vertex) you'll have infinite recursion? Try printing the pointers you look at: `cout << "looking at " << (&v) << endl;` at the beginning of your second `makeEmpty` function. A minimum example reproducing the crash would be great, to be sure.

Comment: @coyotte508, No that doesn't happen, I cout'ed at the end of my make empty and got a dump. The dump literally happens at the end of the last deletion of pointers

Comment: if you cout at the end of the function, and not the beginning, you don't see which vector it studied before it crashes, and if it was already there.

Comment: @coyotte508 I see. I did as you said and got `looking at 0x600038db0
looking at 0x600038df0
looking at 0x600038e30
looking at 0x600038e70
looking at 0x600038e30
Aborted (core dumped)
` There should be more `looking at`

Comment: Well! you have twice `looking at 0x600038e30`, so this means you go twice in the same vector, so you have trouble with double deletes / etc.

Answer (score 0):

"`Vertex* v = new Vertex` I've been told that I do not have to worry about deleting these pointers."

Well, they're raw pointers. You do have to worry about deleting them. But often the easiest solution is to put all your vertices in a `Graph` class, let that own everything, and don't worry about ownership at node level.

Things get a bit hairy if you are cutting graphs in two, or are doing operations which *might* cut a graph in two. But even then, it's usually not too hard to have an operation which extracts a new `Graph` from the old `Graph`, and transfer the affected nodes to the new Graph.

Comment: My Vertices are in a class. Vertex is a struct that is in that class. All my functions that defines ` new Vertex` are also in my class

Comment: @b1234: That probably means the function(s) which `delete` every Vertex should be in the same class.